# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgd

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

So I am trying to compile a program using **make -f Makefile** but I am getting this error **/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgd**

```
root@kevin-VirtualBox://home/kevin/Desktop/makef# make -f Makefile
gcc -o main obj/main.o obj/serial.o obj/fb.o obj/menu_main.o obj/timer.o obj/cmdin.o obj/buzzer.o obj/statemachine.o obj/inout.o obj/network.o obj/text_file_input.o obj/text_file_input_oven.o -I./ -lgd -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgd
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
root@kevin-VirtualBox://home/kevin/Desktop/makef#
```

Makefile:

```
IDIR =./
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
LDIR =./

LIBS=-lgd -lrt

_DEPS = main.h Makefile
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = main.o serial.o fb.o menu_main.o timer.o cmdin.o buzzer.o statemachine.o inout.o network.o text_file_input.o text_file_input_oven.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

after replacing (libgd.a libgd.la libgd.so libgd.so.2 libgd.so.2.0.0) I am getting this error:

```
root@kevin-VirtualBox://home/kevin/Desktop/makef# make -f Makefilegcc -o main obj/main.o obj/serial.o obj/fb.o obj/menu_main.o obj/timer.o obj/cmdin.o obj/buzzer.o obj/statemachine.o obj/inout.o obj/network.o obj/text_file_input.o obj/text_file_input_oven.o -I./ -lgd -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libgd.so when searching for -lgd
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libgd.a when searching for -lgd
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libgd.so when searching for -lgd
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libgd.a when searching for -lgd
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../libgd.so when searching for -lgd
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../libgd.a when searching for -lgd
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgd.so when searching for -lgd
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgd.a when searching for -lgd
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgd
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Comment: You'll have to install it on your system.

Comment: Where is `libgd.a` actually placed? Did you miss specifying an additional library search path with the `-L` option??

Comment: libgd.a is on //usr/bin & //use/lib

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong `libgd` file - they are x86-64 variant, and it would seem that you are not compiling for 32-bit x86? You can use `file somefile` to show what kind of file it is. Try `file obj/serial.o` and compare with `file /usr/lib/libgd.so.2` or whatever - it should show what architecture it's compiled for - I bet it's different!

Comment: hi mats it is obj/serial.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
/usr/lib/libgd.so.2: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

Answer (score 2):

You should have package `libgd-dev` (or `libgd-devel` depending on OS/distribution) installed. The part of the package essential to linking is a symlink `/usr/lib/libgd.so` (usually pointing to `/usr/lib/lib/libgd.so.2`)